# Maclaurin series for sin(x) and cos(x) exceed maximal value

Tags: ruby, math

I have written program which counts sin(x) and cos(x) for input x and n.
Here is a code:

```
def factorial(z)
  if z <= 0
    1
  else
    z * factorial(z-1)
  end
end

def radian(y)
  y%360 * Math::PI / 180
end

puts "Enter x"
x = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter n"
n = gets.chomp.to_i

sin = 0
(0..n).each do |n|
  k = ((-1)**(n))*(radian(x)**((2*n)+1))/factorial((2*n)+1) 
  sin = sin+k
end
puts "Sinus: #{sin}"

cos = 0
(0..n).each do |n|
  l = ((-1)**(n))*(radian(x)**(2*n))/factorial(2*n)
  cos = cos+l
end
puts "Cosinus: #{cos}"
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with program if user input low "n"(steps value) for third and fourth quarter
 For example x = 237, n = 3 sinus and cosinus exceed maximal value.
I think that program should somehow cut an angle, but I have no idea how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readers unfamiliar with the term "Maclauren series", it is merely a Taylor series centered on zero:

```
f(x) ≈ f(0) + f'(0)/1! + f''(0)/2! + f'''(0)/3! +...
```

where `f'`, `f''` and `f'''` denote the first, second and third derivatives of the function `f`.

**Problem**

Let's look at your calculation of `sin`.  It appears you are summing only the odd terms, which is fine, as the even terms are all zero.  Your problem is the numerator of the Maclauran series, which, in your expression, should be the cosine of zero (which equals `1`), alternatively with sign `+` and `-`.  You have the sign right, but rather than `cos(0) #=> 1`, you have computed the angle in radians to the power `2*n+1`.

**Alternative Approach**

Consider the following:

- because `sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2 = 1`, you need only calculate `sin(x)` or `cos(x)` with the Maclauren series. Below I've assumed we're estimating `sin(x)` (in which case `cos(x) = 1-sin(x)**2)**0.5`);
- because the derivative of `sin(x)` is `cos(x)` and the derivative of `cos(x)` is `-sin(x)` and `sin(0)` is zero, we need only calculate the odd terms of the series, whose numerator is alternatively `cos(0)` and `-cos(x)` (1 and -1);
- your computation of factorial is inefficient, since it is only necessary to update the factorial value for each incremented value of `n`;
- as you only work with radians, you may as well convert degrees to radians right after you get the input value for degrees; and
- as you are restricting degrees entered to integer values, you can write `gets.to_i` rather than `gets.chomp.to_i` (the choice is merely stylistic).

First let's make the calculation of factorials more efficient, when they only need be computed for odd values of `n`:

```
def factorial(n)
  if n==1
    @fac = 1
  else
    @fac *= n*(n-1)
  end
end
```

Checking:

```
factorial(1) #=> 1
factorial(3) #=> 6
factorial(5) #=> 120
factorial(7) #=> 5040
```

we can convert from degrees to radians right after getting the input values `x` and `n`:

```
x = radian(x)
```

In view my comments above, the expression used to approximate the value of `sin` reduces to the `n/2` terms:

```
(x**1)/1! - (x**3)/3! + (x**5)/5! - (x**7)/7! +...
```

which we can write as follows:

```
sign = -1
(1..n).step(2).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + (sign *= -1)*(x**i)/factorial(i) }
```

**Code**

Putting this together:

```
def sin_and_cos(x,n)
  sign = -1
  sin = (1..n).step(2).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + (sign *= -1)*(x**i)/factorial(i) }
  cos = (1-sin**2)**0.5
  cos = -cos if (x > 0.5 * Math::PI && x < 1.5 * Math::PI)
  [sin, cos]
end

def factorial(n)
  if n==1
    @fac = 1
  else
    @fac *= n*(n-1)
  end
end

def radian(y)
  y%360 * Math::PI / 180
end
```

**Example**

```
Let's try it:

x = 30
x = radian(30)
  #=> 0.5235987755982988

sin, cos = sin_and_cos(x,5)
  #=> [0.5000021325887924, 0.8660241725302242]
sin, cos = sin_and_cos(x,9)
  #=> [0.5000000000202799, 0.8660254037727301]
sin, cos = sin_and_cos(x,13)
  #=> [0.5, 0.8660254037844386]
```

**Explanation**

Let's look at the calculation of `sin_and_cos(x,n)` when:

```
x = 30
x = radian(30)
  #=> 0.523598
n = 5
```

We first execute

```
sign = -1
```

Next we create an enumerator:

```
enum0 = (1..5).step(2)
  #=>   (1..5).step(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: 1..5:step(2)>
```

We can see the elements of the enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [1, 3, 5]
```

Next, [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`) initializes it's block variable `t` to `0` and then passes each value of the enumerator `enum` into the block, assigning it to the block variable `i`. You should think of using `reduce` whenever you want to compute a sum or product of values from an array, hash or other type of collection, possibly after performing a transformation of each value (e..g, `[1,2,3].reduce(0) { |t,i| t + i*i } #=> 14`.

This is what happens:

*Step 1: pass `i => 1` into the block:*

```
i = 1
t = 0
sign *= -1
  #=> sign = sign * -1 => -1 * -1 = 1
x**i
  #=> 0.523598**1 => 0.523598
factorial(i)
  #=> factorial(1) => 1
t
  #=> 0 + 1 * 0.523598/1
  #=> 0.523598
```

`0.523598` is passed back to `reduce` as the new value of `t`.

*Step 2: pass `i => 3` into the block:*

```
i = 3
t = 0.523598
sign *= -1
  #=> sign = sign * -1 => 1 * -1 = -1
x**i
  #=> 0.523598**3 => 0.1435469
factorial(i)
  #=> factorial(3) => 6
t
  #=> 0.523598 + -1 * 0.1435469/6
  #=> 0.499673
```

`0.499673` is passed back to `reduce` as the new value of `t`.

*Step 3: pass `i => 5` into the block:*

```
i = 5
t = 0.499673
sign *= -1
  #=> sign = sign * -1 => -1 * -1 = 1
x**i
  #=> 0.523598**5 => 0.039354
factorial(i)
  #=> factorial(5) => 120
t
  #=> 0.499673 + 1 * 0.039354/120
  #=> 0.50000095
```

`0.50000095` is passed back to `reduce` as the new value of `t`, but as all elements of the enumerator have now been processed, this value is returned as the approximate value of `sin(0.523598)`.

Lastly we calculate the approximate value of the cosine:

```
cos = (1-sin**2)**0.5
    = (1-0.523598**2)**0.5
  #=> 0.851965
```

and return

```
[0.523598, 0.851965]
```

Note the cosine is positive in the first and fourth quadrants, so

```
  cos = -cos if (x > 0.5 * Math::PI && x < 1.5 * Math::PI)
```

does not change the sign.

As you see, `sign *= -1` just flips the value of `sign` between `1` and `-1`. You could alternatively use `(-1)**(n/2)`.

**Accuracy**

Recall that this approximation is a Taylor's series centered on zero. For degrees close to zero, use of just the first and second derivatives of `sin` provide a good approximation.  For degrees farther from zero, higher-order derivatives are needed to get a reasonably good approximation.

Consider, for example, the `sin` of 30, 150, 210 and 330 degrees.  The first two equal 0.5, the last two, -0.5. Let's see how close the approximation is to each of these for different values of `n`.  We will find that the farther the number of degrees is from zero, the larger `n` must be to produce a close approximation.

First, let's create a method that returns the approximation for `sin` given the number of degrees (not radians) and `n`, rounded to seven decimal digits.

```
def sin_approx(degrees, n)
  x = radian(degrees)
  sin_and_cos(x, n).first.round(7)
end
```

Now let's see what happens for different values of `n`:

```
n = 5
sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5000021
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.6522731
sin_approx(210, n) #=>  0.9709643
sin_approx(330, n) #=> 26.7331389

n = 7
sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.4850294
sin_approx(210, n) #=> -0.7920105
sin_approx(330, n) #=> -14.9834333

n = 10
sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.5009498
sin_approx(210, n) #=> -0.4630779
sin_approx(330, n) #=>  4.2368035

n = 14
sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.5000014
sin_approx(210, n) #=> -0.4997892
sin_approx(330, n) #=> -0.3269112

n = 20
sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.5
sin_approx(210, n) #=> -0.5
sin_approx(330, n) #=> -0.5001706
```

We can improve accuracy for a given value of `n` by using the series expansion to estimate the `sine` of angles between `0` and `90`, and deriving the sine for degrees greater than `90`:

```
R0_90    = (0.0..0.5*Math::PI)
R90_180  = (0.5*Math::PI...Math::PI)
R180_270 = (Math::PI...1.5*Math::PI)

def sin_and_cos(x,n)
  s = sin(x,n)
  cos = (1-s**2)**0.5
  cos = -cos if (R90_180.cover?(x) || R180_270.cover?(x))
  [s, cos]
end

def sin(x,n)
  sign = [1, -1].cycle
  sin =
    case(x)
    when R0_90
      (1..n).step(2).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + (sign.next)*(x**i)/factorial(i) }
    when R90_180
      sin(Math::PI-x,n)
    else
      -sin(x-Math::PI,n)          
    end
end

sin_approx( 30, n) #=>  0.5000021
sin_approx(150, n) #=>  0.5000021
sin_approx(210, n) #=> -0.5000021
sin_approx(330, n) #=> -0.5000021
```

**Summing up**

Incorporating the above improvements, the code is as follows:

```
R0_90    = (0.0..0.5*Math::PI)
R90_180  = (0.5*Math::PI...Math::PI)
R180_270 = (Math::PI...1.5*Math::PI)

def factorial(n)
  if n==1
    @fac = 1
  else
    @fac *= n*(n-1)
  end
end

def radian(y)
  y%360 * Math::PI / 180
end

def sin(x,n)
  sign = [1, -1].cycle
  sin =
    case(x)
    when R0_90
      (1..n).step(2).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + (sign.next)*(x**i)/factorial(i) }
    when R90_180
      sin(Math::PI-x,n)
    else
      -sin(x-Math::PI,n)          
    end
end

def sin_and_cos(x,n)
  s = sin(x,n)
  cos = (1-s**2)**0.5
  cos = -cos if (R90_180.cover?(x) || R180_270.cover?(x))
  [s, cos]
end

def sin_and_cos_approx(degrees, n)
  x = radian(degrees)
  s, c = sin_and_cos(x, n)
  [s.round(7), c.round(7)]
end
```

Let's try it:

```
n = 5
sin_and_cos_approx( 30, n) #=> [ 0.5000021,  0.8660242]
sin_and_cos_approx(150, n) #=> [ 0.5000021, -0.8660242]
sin_and_cos_approx(210, n) #=> [-0.5000021, -0.8660242]
sin_and_cos_approx(330, n) #=> [-0.5000021,  0.8660242]

n = 7
sin_and_cos_approx( 30, n) #=> [ 0.5,  0.8660254]
sin_and_cos_approx(150, n) #=> [ 0.5, -0.8660254]
sin_and_cos_approx(210, n) #=> [-0.5, -0.8660254]
sin_and_cos_approx(330, n) #=> [-0.5,  0.8660254]
```

Comment: I don't understand `def sin_and_cos(x,n)` part. Can you explain how this part of code works step by step? I'm having problems with implementation it to my own code.

Comment: Gregy, I provided the explanation you requested. Please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Thank you, it seems clear for me now, but still program returns strange data of sinus or cosinus from third and fourth quarter. It only happens for low "n" value. I have used n = 5 as in your example and every angle with degree higher than 210 and lower than 360 is failing.

Comment: Gregy, please see the section **Accuracy** that I've added.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Do you mean that there is no possibility to calculate sin(x) and cos(x) for x in range of 210-360 degrees with small number of steps?

Comment: Think about what a sine wave looks like.  If we use the series expansion to estimate `sin(d)` for `d` between zero and 90 degrees, we can derive the sin for any angle between 90 and 360 degrees. If `d` is between 90 and 180 degrees, `sin(d) = sin(180-d)`, where `180-d` would be between 0 and 90 degrees.  For example, if `d=160`, `sin(160) = sin(20) ~ 0.342`. If `d` is between 180 and 360 degrees, `sin(d) = -sin(d-180)`. If, for example, `d=320`, `sin(320)=-sin(140)`, but we know `sin(140)=sin(180-140)=sin(40)`, so `sin(320)=-sin(40) ~ -0.643`.

Comment: I did an edit at the end to implement my comment above.

Comment: Cary thank you a lot, it is what I was looking for. With improved accuracy it works perfect.

Comment: Hey Cary, can I ask you for one more thing? I have found some troubles with using your's code with accuracy implementation for cosx. Can you guide me how should whole code look like for sin&cos counting? I'm lack of experiance and I would like to make it DRY.

Comment: I did another edit at the end. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: It works great, but it's missing change sign part for cosine. It was the hardest part for me when I was trying to do it by myself. I don't know how to keep it DRY and include sign changes for cosine.